# Auto load TR while scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please i've got about 5000 rows of data with live edits...
I want to be able to show the first 200 rows then show the next 200 rows as the users scrolls down the page.. and probably hide the previous 200 rows...
After a few search on stackoverflow..  i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406845/ajax-limit-the-loading-of-a-list-and-then-load-the-rest-on-scroll) code but dont seem to understand it much

```
    <table id="loadingtable" cellpadding="0" border="1" cellspacing="3" align="center" width="80%">
    <?php
    function createtr($value, $stop)
    {
        while($value <= $stop){
            echo'<tr>';
                echo '<td>';
                    echo "cell {$value}";
                echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            $value++;
        }
    }
    
    createtr(1, 5000);
    ?>  
    </table>
```

And Here's the Jquery

```
       $("#loadingtable tr").slice(100).hide();
       
        var mincount = 100;
        var maxcount = 100; 
    
        $(window).scroll(function() 
        {
            if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 400) {
                    $("#loadingtable tr").slice(mincount,maxcount).fadeIn(800);
            mincount = mincount+100;
            maxcount = maxcount+100
        
        }
    });
```

The Code doesn't work for..
Please help
Thannks a lot..

Comment: start with mincount = 0

Comment: @Techmonk ive tried your suggestion.. but didnt work..

Comment: try the one in the answer

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#loadingtable tr").slice(100).hide();

    var mincount = 0;
    var maxcount = 100; 

    $(window).scroll(function() 
    {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height() - 400) {
            $("#loadingtable tr").slice(mincount,maxcount).fadeOut(800);
            mincount = mincount+100;
            maxcount = maxcount+100;
            $("#loadingtable tr").slice(mincount,maxcount).fadeIn(800);

    }
if($(window).scrollTop() <= 200) {
        $("#loadingtable tr").slice(mincount,maxcount).fadeOut(800);
        mincount = mincount-100;
        maxcount = maxcount-100;
        $("#loadingtable tr").slice(mincount,maxcount).fadeIn(800);

}
});
```

This will load the next 100 rows when the user has scrolled to the bottom of the page - 400 pixles. To also hide the above rows you will need to add a similar function first to unhide when he starts to scroll up and then use FadeOut

You would need to add checks for the border conditions (mincount < 0 and maxcount > 5000)

Comment: Thnx.. got it to work... i would like to hide the previous rows.. do you know how i can go about that?.. im still a newbie at Jquery.. :) thnx

Comment: P.S. This would go horribly wrong if the user has a screen size > your page length-600 px

Comment: tried the code.. but it hides all rows instead :( without fading in the next 100 rows...

Comment: And more importantly did you add the border condition check ? Not to hide rows if mincount =0 and max count = 5000 ?

Comment: Ive not added that yet.. Im trying to use it inside a div with overflow.. but the little scroll start fading in rows..

Comment: that is cause you run into the border condition... you need to put that firsts or else everything would be hidden at first scroll as it tries to load -100 to 0 + I would in this kind of situation keep 200 rows visible and hide 0 - 100 when I show 200-300 or else it will be annoying for the user when everythiing changes

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25500/discussion-between-user1862764-and-techmonk)

Comment: @Techmonk Had to edit the code a bit, as I did not require the `fadeOut` just `fadeIn`But a big thank you for helping me out.